# JavaScript audio multi track player

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playlist

I am new to this and I hope someone could help me to finish this JavaScript code by enabling it to pull the img of the audio links provided.

As it does now with the play and pause and next song

Here is the full code:

```js
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 
    function loadPlayer() {
        var audioPlayer = new Audio();
        audioPlayer.controls="";
        audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended',nextSong,false);
        audioPlayer.addEventListener('error',errorFallback,true);
        document.getElementById("player").appendChild(audioPlayer);
        nextSong();
    }
    function nextSong() {
        if(urls[next]!=undefined) {
            var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
            if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
                audioPlayer.src=urls[next];
                audioPlayer.load();
                audioPlayer.play();
                next++;
            } else {
                loadPlayer();
            }
        } else {
            alert('Error due to end Of Stations list or the Web Browser is not supported. Please use with Google Chrome');
        }
    }
    function errorFallback() {
            nextSong();
    }
    function playPause() {
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
            if (audioPlayer.paused) {
                audioPlayer.play();
            } else {
                audioPlayer.pause();
            }
        } else {
            loadPlayer();
        }
    }
    function pickSong(num) {
        next = num;
        nextSong();
    }

 
    var urls = new Array();
    
    urls[-1] = 'http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9079/jet_143844.mp3';
    urls[-2] = 'http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9077/jet_143651.mp3';
    urls[-3] = 'http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9077/jet_143651.mp3';
    urls[-4] = 'http://francemaghreb2.ice.infomaniak.ch:80/francemaghreb2-high.mp3';
var next = 0;
 
</script>
```

```html
<!-- player start -->
<a href="#" onclick="playPause()" id="player" title="Play">Play</a>
<a href="#" onclick="playPause()" id="player" title="Stop">Stop</a>
<a href="#" onclick="nextSong()" id="player" title="Next Station">Next Track</a>

<!-- player ends -->

<br>
<br>
<!-- img links start -->

<a href="#" onclick="pickSong(-1)">
  <img src="radio/radio almazighia.png" />
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="pickSong(-2)">
  <img src="radio/alwatania.png" />
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="pickSong(-3)">
  <img src="radio/inter.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="pickSong(-4)">
  <img src="radio/france maghrib.jpg" />
</a>

<!-- img links ends -->
```

Comment: Why are you using a negative index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to rework your code. Thanks to your comment I could implement the thing that you want. When the user starts a radio station it shows the image of the radio station next to the play link.

I've improved some things:

- No global variables anymore
- Script and audioplayer is loaded when the page is loaded
- Play and Stop are disabled on start up.
- When a file is loaded the play event is fired through an event. This means that the file/stream has to be loaded sufficiently for the audio element to play. When this is valid the controls are enabled.
- Show image of radio station on selection.
- Playing starts when the user selects a radio station.
- Add new radio stations be simply adding a new item to the array. Item is added a with to items `[stream uri, radio station image]`.
- Used `javascript: void(0)` in link's href instead of `#` to prevent page from jumping up.

Hope you like it.

```js
 function loadPlayer() 
 {
        var audioPlayer = new Audio();
        audioPlayer.controls="";
  audioPlayer.setAttribute("data-index", -1); //set default index to -1.
        audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended',nextSong,false);
        audioPlayer.addEventListener('error',errorFallback,true);
        document.getElementById("player").appendChild(audioPlayer);
    }
 
 
    function nextSong(index, e) 
 {
  var next;
  var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  //check for index. If so load from index. If not, index is defined auto iterate to next value.
  if (index >= 0)
  {
   next = index;
  }
  else
  {
   next = parseInt(audioPlayer.getAttribute("data-index"))+1;
   next >= urls.length ? next = 0 : null;
  }

  audioPlayer.src=urls[next][0]; //load the url.
  audioPlayer.setAttribute("data-index", next);
  //disable the player.
  var audioPlayerControls = document.getElementById("playerControls");
  audioPlayer.removeEventListener('canplay',enablePlayerControls,false);
  audioPlayerControls.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  audioPlayer.addEventListener('canplay',enablePlayerControls,false);
  audioPlayer.load();
  
  //show the image:
  var image = document.getElementById("playerList").querySelectorAll("a")[next].querySelector("img").cloneNode();
  image.style.width = "30px";
  if(audioPlayerControls.querySelector("img"))
  {
   audioPlayerControls.replaceChild(image, audioPlayerControls.querySelector("img"));
  }
  else
  {
   audioPlayerControls.insertBefore(image, audioPlayerControls.querySelector("a"));
  }
  
    }
 
 function enablePlayerControls()
 {
  //File has loaded, so we can start playing the audio. 
  //Enable the player options.
  var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  audioPlayer.removeEventListener('canplay',enablePlayerControls,false);
  document.getElementById("playerControls").removeAttribute("disabled");
  audioPlayer.play();
 }
 
    function errorFallback() {
        nextSong();
    }
 
 
    function playPause() 
 {
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  if (audioPlayer.paused) 
  {
   audioPlayer.play();
  } else 
  {
   audioPlayer.pause();
  }
    }
    function pickSong(e) 
 {
  //we want the correct target. Select it via the event (e).
  var target;
  
  //pickSong does the selecting:
  if (e && e.target && e.target.tagName && e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img")
  {
        //The event target = the img element.
   target = e.target.parentElement;
  }
  else
  {
   //the event target is the a element
   target = e.target;
  }
  var index = target.getAttribute("data-index"); //get the song index stored in the data-index attribute.
        nextSong(index);
    }
 
    var urls = new Array();
    urls[0] = ['http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9079/jet_143844.mp3', 'radio/radio almazighia.png'];
    urls[1] = ['http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9077/jet_143651.mp3', "radio/alwatania.png"];
    urls[2] = ['http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9077/jet_143651.mp3', "radio/inter.jpg"];
    urls[3] = ['http://francemaghreb2.ice.infomaniak.ch:80/francemaghreb2-high.mp3', "radio/france maghrib.jpg"];

 function startAudioPlayer()
 {
  loadPlayer();
  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i)
  {
   //this for loop runs through all urls and appends them to the player list. This smooths the adding off new items. You only have
   //to declare them in the array, the script does the rest.
   var link = document.createElement("a");
   link.href = "javascript: void(0)";
   link.addEventListener("click", pickSong, false);
   link.setAttribute("data-index", i);
   link.img = document.createElement("img");
   link.img.src = urls[i][1];
   link.appendChild(link.img);
   document.getElementById("playerList").appendChild(link);
  }
 } 
 
    //Event that starts the audio player.
 window.addEventListener("load", startAudioPlayer, false);
```

```css
  #playerControls[disabled=true] > a{
   color: #c3c3c3;
  }
```

```html
<span id="playerControls" disabled="true">
 <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="playPause()" id="player" title="Play">Play</a>
 <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="playPause()" id="player" title="Stop">Stop</a>
</span>
 <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="nextSong()" id="player" title="Next Station">Next Track</a>

<!-- player ends -->

<br>
<br>
<!-- img links start -->

<div id="playerList">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank Mouser ! What I want is when you click on the img, I like that img to be put along the play and stop

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="playPause()" id="player" title="Play">Play</a>
<a href="#" onclick="playPause()" id="player" title="Stop">Stop</a>
<a href="#" onclick="nextSong()" id="player" title="Next Station">Next Track</a>

Comment: Hi there. the above works great in most browsers apart from iphone running on fullscreen mode. the audio wont play at all. Is there way to bypass that?

Comment: @c.ouggag I couldn't really say why IPhone isn't rendering this correctly. What isn't working on the iPhone?

Comment: Hi. it won't play audio when i run it from home screen as fullscreen. it works fine in  iphone safari browser but not as fullscreen.

Comment: @c.ouggag, I cannot help you with this, I'm really no expert on the inner workings of the IPhone.

Comment: No,worries. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Could you please help me to find out why this won't work on safari browser? It seems to work really well in all other browsers apart from Safari. Any help will be most appreciated.